# What is "Enjoy popularity" meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not a native speaker so it's quite confusing. 
A guy said:

> "Vietnamese girls enjoy their popularity among Chinese man and I'm one of them"

My question is: This guy here is trying to say that "young Chinese man like Vietnamese girls and so do I" - Am I correct? Or I should understand that "Vietnamese girls are famous in China and they (Vietnamese girls) enjoy that"?

Comment: Among should be followed by a plural noun - men.

Comment: What was the context? Can you see the speaker and confirm that he is a Chinese man?

Answer (score 1):

First off, as the sentence constructed, if you hadn't mentioned the gender, it wouldn't be clear who the speaker is--one of the girls or one of Chinese men.

As for the meaning of the verb *to enjoy* here, it is *to take delight in and make the most of something*, and in your sentence that something is the *girls'popularity among Chinese men*.

To avoid ambiguity in reading a stand-alone sentence, I'd add "one of those girls/men" at the end:

> Vietnamese girls enjoy their popularity among Chinese men, and I'm one
>   of those girls (men).

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a couple different points in post...

> "Vietnamese girls enjoy their popularity among Chinese man and I'm one of them"

Looking at just the sample sentence, I thought the speaker was one of the Vietnamese girls, who *enjoy*/*like*/*appreciate the benefits* of being popular with Chinese men.

Since we know the speaker is a guy, the meaning of the sentence changes: "...and I'm one of them" tells us that the speaker is one of the Chinese men who like Vietnamese girls.

> My question is: This guy here is trying to say that "young Chinese man like Vietnamese girls and so do I" - Am I correct?

No, you're not quite correct. When you say "and so do I," you're implying that you have the same interests as another person or group but you're not actually part of the group. In this case, you might be a Japanese man instead of a Chinese man, or you could even be a Nigerian woman. What you have in common is that you like Vietnamese girls.